# In Rails, how do I access the Request.ServerVariables like you do in ASP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http-request

I want to access a given Requests ServerVariables, but I can't seem to find anything on Google on how to get access to the Server Vars of the request object.  How do I do this or am I doomed to simply never know?

***An example of why I'd want to do this (but not actually what I want to do):***
User logs in, and you want to store the IP address of place where they logged in, or perhaps I want to record the user-agent or referer from the browser that they are viewing the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should look at the `request` object that's available from the controller. There are a bunch of methods like

`request.remote_ip`

you can read more about the [Request object](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html) on the Rails API site

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but why i press the link but i cant find request object documentation anymore?

Comment: Looks like Rails 3.0 is now the current documentation (hence the broken link) Here's the updated equivalent that I could find. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html

Answer (score 0):

The `request` accessor in a controller returns an ActionDispatch::Request object which can access all of the server variables you would expect.

Best documentation I've found for it is here: http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/ActionDispatch/Request

Sometimes you have methods like `request.remote_ip` as mentioned in the other answer, other times you can access things via `request.env`, for example, to get the user agent, use `request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]`